# How to determine when EditText has completed its initialization?

Tags: android, android-edittext, initialization, listener, selection

I have a custom `EditText` where I override `onSelectionChange` to notify to observers when cursor position has changed. There is a little delay to prevent notifying too often when selection is changing rapidly (*backpressure*).

```
private static final long POST_SELECTION_CHANGED_DELAY = 500;

private Runnable mSelectionRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      if (mSelectionListener != null) {
         mSelectionListener.onSelectionChanged();
      }
   }
};

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
   super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
   postSelectionChanged();
}

private void postSelectionChanged() {
   removeCallbacks(mSelectionRunnable);
   postDelayed(mSelectionRunnable, POST_SELECTION_CHANGED_DELAY);
}
```

The problem is that during `EditText` initialization phase `onSelectionChanged` is raised at least once and that notifies my observers even if it's not already needed. I tried attaching listeners after a 1s delay, but that seems hacky to me.

So, is there a way to know when `EditText` initialization has completed so I can attach my listeners there? I already tried `onAttachedToWindow` but it's too early.

Comment: View is visible to user after `onDraw` returns .. Try setting a flag after `super.onDraw()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe override onFocusChanged method?

```kotlin
override fun onFocusChanged(focused: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {}
```

So you can detect if EditText is focused and then proceed with your custom logic